# Powershell stdout flush

Tags: powershell

How to force STDOUT flush in PowerShell? I've tried with Console.Out.Flush() but it seems to be waiting for some argument.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: yes!  echo "ready!"; Console.Out.Flush(); break; --> "An expression was expected after '('.""

Comment: Oh, I just messed up with PS syntax: [Console]::Out.Flush() works. thanks

Comment: Submit that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

To force STDOUT flush in PowerShell

```
 [Console]::Out.Flush()
```